# PHP script keeps doing mmap/munmap

Tags: php, performance, cpu, mmap

My PHP script contains a loop, which does nothing much more than echoing and dereferencing pointers (like in $tab[$othertab[$i]]-> stuff).

It was working great until yesterday, when this script starting being VERY slow (like 50 times slower than before).

After using strace, i figured out that 90% of the time, the script does mmap/munmap.
Here is a random portion of the strace log :

```
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
munmap(0x7fac0156c000, 266240)          = 0
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0156c000
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac0152b000
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fac014ea000
```

Here is the result of the strace -c command :

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 82.77    0.004092           0     13542           mmap
  9.69    0.000479           0      3642           write
  7.54    0.000373           0     13541           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0       100           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        88           poll
  0.00    0.000000           0        25         4 access
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.004944                 30938         4 total
```

Here is the php script :

```
function affAnnonce($tabAnnonces, $isDoublon = 0)
{
    GLOBAL $db, $base, $tabDomaine, $doublon, $traduction, $tab_contrat, $tab_emploi, $tab_categ,
    $tab_metier, $tab_region, $tab_departement, $tab_secteur, $tab_experience, $calc_all, $tabLangues, $tabLanguesNiveau, $tabNoAffAnnonce, $tabHisto;

    foreach($tabAnnonces AS $tmp) {
        if (in_array($tmp['id'], $tabNoAffAnnonce) === true) {
            continue;
        }
        $value->host    = "../";
        foreach($tabDomaine AS $domaine => $valeur) {
            if ($domaine == $tmp['domaine']) {
                $value->host    = $valeur->host;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Ordre
        // secteur;metier;contrat;emploi;region;langues;domaine
        $tabPushModif   = array();
        if ($tmp['push_preview'] != '') {
            $tabPushModif   = explode(';', $tmp['push_preview']);
            $tabPushModif['secteur']    = $tabPushModif[0];
            $tabPushModif['metier']     = $tabPushModif[1];
            $tabPushModif['contrat']    = $tabPushModif[2];
            $tabPushModif['id_emploi']  = $tabPushModif[3];
            $tabPushModif['regions']    = $tabPushModif[4];
            $tabPushModif['langues']    = $tabPushModif[5];
            $tabPushModif['domaine']    = $tabPushModif[6];
        }
        $infoSoc    = get_nom_societe($tmp['id_societe']);
        $number = ($tmp['nb_preview_push'] != '' ? $tmp['nb_preview_push'] : '&nbsp;');
        $secteurs = explode ("/", $tmp[secteur]);
        $sector = "";
        $count_sect = count($secteurs);
        for ($k = 0; $k < $count_sect; $k++) {
            if ($secteurs[$k] != '') {
                $sector .= $tab_secteur[$secteurs[$k]].'/';
            }
        }
        $tmp['poste']   = apresinsertion($tmp['poste']);
        $tmp['metier']  = $tab_metier[$tmp['metier']];
        $tmp['region']  = $tab_region[$tmp['region']];
        $tmp['departement'] = $tab_departement[$tmp['departement']];
        $tmp['secteur'] = $sector;
        $tmp['id_contrat'] = $tmp['contrat'];
        $tmp['contrat'] = $tab_contrat[$tmp['contrat']];
        $tmp['emploi']  = $tab_emploi[$tmp['id_emploi']];
        $tmp['categorie']   = $tab_categ[$tmp['categorie']];
        echo '<tr id="'.($isDoublon ? 'dbl_' : '').$tmp['id'].'"><td align="center" class="tdFirst nowrap dbl_'.$tmp['id'].'" id="aff_'.$tmp['id'].'"';
        switch($tmp['affiche']) {
            case '0': echo ' bgcolor=#DBB7FF'; break;
            default : ;
        }
        echo '><a href=?op=annonces&search4='.$tmp[id].' target=_new>'.$tmp[id].'</a><br />';
        echo '<a href="'.$value->host.'" target="blank">'.strtoupper($tmp['domaine']).'<br /><img src="../images/flags/'.$tmp['domaine'].'.png" border=0 align=middle></a>';
        echo '</TD><TD align=center class=tdNext';
        if ($tmp['filtre'] == 1)
            echo ' bgcolor=#FF0000';
        echo '>';
        if ($isDoublon)
            echo '<a id="'.$tmp['id'].'" class="doublon" href="#">DOUBLON</a> - ';
        if (($tmp[id_reponse] == 1) || ($tmp[id_reponse] == 2) || ($tmp[id_reponse] == 4) || ($tmp[id_reponse] == 5))
            echo '<a href="javascript:voir_annonce(\''.$tmp['id'].'\', \''.$value->host.'\')" onMouseOver="showPreview('.$tmp['id'].');" onMouseOut="hidePreview('.$tmp['id'].');">'.$tmp['poste'].'</a>';
        if ($tmp[id_reponse] == 3)
            echo '<a href="javascript:voir_annonce3(\''.$tmp['url_reponse'].'\')" onMouseOver="showPreview('.$tmp['id'].');" onMouseOut="hidePreview('.$tmp['id'].');">'.$tmp['poste'].'</a>';
        if ($tmp['urgent'] == 1)
            print " - <font class=r_bold>urgent</font>";
        if ($tmp['gold'] == 1)
            print " - <font class=g_bold>gold</font>";
        if ($tmp['cvtheque'] == 1)
            print " - CVthèque";
        if ($tmp['url_reponse'] != '' && $tmp['id_reponse'] != 3) {
            echo '<br /><br />URL - ';
            $len = strlen($tmp['url_reponse']);
            if ($len > 50) {
                $link = substr($tmp['url_reponse'], 0, 47).'...';
            } else {
                $link = $tmp['url_reponse'];
            }
            echo '<a href="'.$tmp['url_reponse'].'" style="color: #666;" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>';
        }
        // Début du div ou sera placé l'annonce
        echo '<br /><div id="preview_'.$tmp['id'].'" name="preview_'.$tmp['id'].'" class="tdStyle1" style="z-index: 1000; display: none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #666; background: #fff; text-align: left; width: 777px;" onMouseOver="showPreview('.$tmp['id'].');" onMouseOut="hidePreview('.$tmp['id'].');">';
        $tmp["url"] = substr($tmp["url"], 7);
        $id_modele  = getIdModeleByAnnonce($tmp['id_societe'], $tmp["id"], $tmp['domaine']);
        $tmp["poste"] = mb_strtoupper($tmp["poste"]);
        $isFnh = isFnhAnnonce($tmp['id']);
        $logo = "";
        if ($isFnh) {
            $logo_jpg = getFnhLogo();
            $logo = "<img align='center' border='0' src='".$logo_jpg."' />";
        } else {
            if ($id_modele > 0) {
                if ($tmp['id_reponse'] == 1) {
                    $logo_gif = "../fichiers/societes/".$tmp['id_societe']."/".$id_modele.".gif";
                    if (file_exists($logo_gif)) {
                        $logo = "<img align=center border=0 src=".$logo_gif.">";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $rep = "../fichiers/societes/".$tmp['id_societe']."/".$id_modele;
                    $logo_jpg = $rep.".jpg";
                    $logo_swf = $rep.".swf";
                    $logo_gif = $rep.".gif";
                    if (file_exists($logo_jpg)) {
                        $logo = "<img align=center border=0 src=".$logo_jpg.">";
                    }
                    elseif (file_exists($logo_swf))
                        $logo = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                            codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"
                            width="120" height="600">
                            <param name=movie value="'.$logo_swf.'">
                            <param name=quality value=high>
                            <embed src="'.$logo_swf.'"
                            quality=high
                            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
                            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="120" height="600"></embed>
                            </object>';
                    elseif (file_exists($logo_gif)) {
                        $logo = "<img align=center border=0 src=".$logo_gif.">";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            if (strlen($logo) > 0 && strlen($tmp['url']) > 0)
                $logo   = "<a href=http://".$tmp['url']." target=_blank>".$logo."</a>";
        if (strlen($tmp['url_reponse']) <= 0) {
            $tmp['url_reponse'] = "../jobs/repondre_annonce.php?id=".$tmp['id']."\" onClick=\"";
            if ($tmp['contact_email'] == "")
                $tmp['url_reponse'] .= "alert('".$traduction->aff_word("repondre_courrier", $tabTrad['only_word']).'\n'.$tmp['societe'].'\n'.str_replace("<br />", '\n', ereg_replace("[\r\n\t]", "", $tmp['adresse']))."');";
            else
                $tmp['url_reponse'] .= "popUp(this.href, 'scroll', 540, 400);";
            $tmp['url_reponse'] .= "return false;";
        }
        ?>
        <table width="775" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border=0>
        <? if ($tmp['id_reponse'] != "2") { ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="575" align=center valign=top>
                    <table width="535" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="nom_societe"><?=$tmp['societe']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr size=1 color=#000000></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="right"><?=date_2fr($tmp["date_affichage"], 1)?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("pays")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['pays0']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    if ($tmp['region']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("region")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['region']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['departement']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("departement")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['departement']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['ville']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("ville")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['ville']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['debut']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("debut_travail")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['debut']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("type_contrat")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['contrat']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    if ($tmp['emploi']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("type_emploi")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['emploi']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['salaire']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("salaire")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['salaire']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['experience']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("experience_metier")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tab_experience[$tmp['experience']]?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['reference']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("reference")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td align="left"><?=$tmp['reference']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    if ($tmp['presentation']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign=top align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("presentation")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: justify;"><?=$tmp['presentation']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class=bold align="right"><?=$traduction->aff_word("poste")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td valign="top" class=titre_poste align=center><?=$tmp['poste']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class=bold align="right"><?=$traduction->aff_word("description")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td style="text-align: justify;"><?=$tmp['description']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width=100%>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width=405><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    if ($tmp['profil']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("profil")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="text-align: justify;"><?=$tmp['profil']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['recommandation']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="left"></td>
                            <td valign="top" style="text-align: justify;"><?=$tmp['recommandation']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['contact_nom'] || $tmp['contact_prenom']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="right" class=bold><?=$traduction->aff_word("contact")?>&nbsp;:</td>
                            <td valign="top" align="left"><?=$tmp['contact_prenom']?>&nbsp;<?=$tmp['contact_nom']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><hr size=1 color=#000000 width=405></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? } ?>
        <? } elseif ($tmp['domaine'] != 'de') { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2><table width="755" align=right valign=top><tr><td><?=$tmp['presentation']?></td></tr></table></td>
            </tr>
        <? } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan=6>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><a href="<?=$tmp['url_reponse']?>" target="_blank">&gt;&gt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("repondre_en_ligne")?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="../jobs/affiche_imprime_annonce.php?id=<?=$tmp['id']?>" onClick="popUp(this.href, 'scroll', 540, 400);return false;" target="_blank">&gt;&gt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("version_imprimer")?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="../jobs/send_friend_annonce.php?id=<?=$tmp['id']?>" onClick="popUp(this.href, 'clean', 400, 300);return false;" target="_blank">&gt;&gt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("envoi_ami")?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="./affiche_liste.php?soc=<?=$tmp['societe_clean']?>">&gt;&gt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("toutes_offres")?> <?=$tmp['societe']?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="../jobs/index.php">&gt;&gt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("nouvelle_recherche")?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="../jobs/index.php" onClick="javascript:retour(); return false;">&lt;&lt;&nbsp;<?=$traduction->aff_word("retour")?></a></td>
                        </tr>
        <? if ($tmp['id_reponse'] != "2") { ?>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="200" align=center class=black_bord valign=top>
                    <table width="190" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" class=bold><? if ($tmp['id_reponse'] != "5") { ?><br><? } ?><?=$logo?><br><br><?=$tmp['societe']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?
                    if ($tmp['adresse']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan=2><?=$tmp['adresse']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['contact_tel']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=bold align=right><?=$traduction->aff_word("tel")?> :</td>
                            <td align=center><?=$tmp['contact_tel']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['contact_fax']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class=bold align=right><?=$traduction->aff_word("fax")?> :</td>
                            <td align=center><?=$tmp['contact_fax']?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? }
                    if ($tmp['url']) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=2 align=center><a href="http://<?=$tmp['url']?>" target="_blank"><?=$tmp['url']?></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <? } ?>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <? } ?>
        </table>
        <?
        echo '</div>';
        // Fin du div ou sera placé l'annonce
        echo "</TD><TD align=center class=tdNext><b>".date_2fr($tmp['date_creation'], 1)."</b><br>".date_2fr($tmp['date_affichage'], 1);
        echo "</TD><TD align=center class=tdNext>".$tmp[societe]."<br>(<i><a href=".$value->host."login/login.php?login=".$infoSoc->email."&pass=".$infoSoc->password." target=_blank>".$infoSoc->nom."</a></i>)<br><a href=index.php?op=entreprise&ac=tableau_bord&id_societe=".$tmp['id_societe'].">compte</a></TD>";
        $color = '';
        switch($tmp[push_mail]) {
                case "0": $color = " bgcolor=#DBB7FF"; break;
                case "2": $color = " bgcolor=#CCCCCC"; break;
                default :  ;
        }
        $type_rep = "";
        switch ($tmp[id_reponse]) {
            case 1:
                $type_rep = "Standard";
            break;
            case 2:
                $type_rep = "Chartée";
            break;
            case 3:
                $type_rep = "Metamoteur";
            break;
            case 4:
                $type_rep = "Reponse sur site";
            break;
            case 5:
                $type_rep = "Semi-chartée";
            break;
        }
        print "
        <td align=center class=tdNext>
            <table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>".$tmp['contrat']." - ".$tmp['emploi']."</td>
                    <td $color align=center rowspan=4 width=40%>
                        <a onclick=\"javascript:colorannonce(this, '#CFFFCF');\" href=?op=agentalertes&action=modify_push&amp;id_annonce=".$tmp[id]." target=_blank>Modifier push</a><br><br>
                        <a onclick=\"sendPush(this, ".$tmp['id']."); return false;\" href=\"#\">Envoyer Push</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>".(strlen($tmp['metier']) > 0 ? $tmp['metier'] : '<font class=gris_i>'.$tmp['categorie'].'</font>')."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>".$tmp[secteur]."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center>".($number < 500 ? '<font color="red">' : ($number > 1500 ? '<font color="orange">' : '<font color="green">')).$number."</font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align=center class=tdNext>
            <table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>";
        if (strlen($tabPushModif['regions']) > 0) {
            $tab    = explode('/', $tabPushModif['regions']);
            foreach($tab AS $elem) {
                if (strlen($elem) <= 0)
                    continue;
                if (strpos($elem, 'dep-') !== false) {
                    echo $tab_departement[substr($elem, 4)];
                    $query_tmp  = 'SELECT region FROM ref_departement WHERE id = "'.substr($elem, 4).'"';
                    $obj    = $db->getObj($query_tmp);
                    if ($obj) {
                        echo ' - '.$tab_region[$obj->region];
                        $query_tmp = 'SELECT rp.code_pays FROM ref_pays rp INNER JOIN ref_region rr ON rr.pays = rp.id WHERE rr.id = "'.$obj->region.'"';
                        $obj    = $db->getObj($query_tmp);
                        if ($obj)
                            echo ' ('.$obj->code_pays.')';
                    }
                }
                elseif (is_numeric($elem) === false) {
                    echo '<font class=gris_i>'.$tmp['departement'].' - '.$tmp['region'].'</font> ('.$elem.')';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<font class=gris_i>'.$tmp['departement'].'</font> - '.$tab_region[$elem];
                    $query_tmp = 'SELECT rp.code_pays FROM ref_pays rp INNER JOIN ref_region rr ON rr.pays = rp.id WHERE rr.id = "'.$obj->region.'"';
                    $obj    = $db->getObj($query_tmp);
                    if ($obj)
                        echo ' ('.$obj->code_pays.')';
                }
            }
        }
        else
            echo $tmp['departement']." - ".$tmp['region']." (".$tmp['code_pays'].")";
        echo "</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>".$tmp[ville]."</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>";
        if (strlen($tabPushModif['metier']) > 0) {
            $tmpExp = array();
            $tab    = explode('/', $tabPushModif['metier']);
            foreach($tab AS $elem) {
                if (strlen($elem) <= 0)
                    continue;
                $tmpMetier  = explode('-', $elem);
                if (isset($tmpMetier[1])) {
                    if (in_array($tmpMetier[1], $tmpExp) === true)
                        continue;
                    $tmpExp[]   = $tmpMetier[1];
                    if ($tmpMetier[1] == $tmp['experience'])
                        echo '<b>'.$tab_experience[$tmpMetier[1]].'</b>/';
                    else
                        echo $tab_experience[$tmpMetier[1]].'/';
                }
            }
            if (count($tmpExp) <= 0)
                echo '<font class=gris_i>'.$tab_experience[$tmp['experience']].'</font>';
        }
        else
            echo $tab_experience[$tmp['experience']];
        echo "</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center>".$tabLangues[$tmp['id_langue']]->langue." - ".$tabLanguesNiveau[$tmp['id_langue_niveau']]->langue_niveau."</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        <td align=center class=tdNext>
            <table width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas>$type_rep</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center>".$tmp[compteur_vu]."&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href=?op=gcand&ac=liste&id_annonce=".$tmp[id]."&statut=all target=_new>".$tmp[compteur_repondu]."</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        <td align=center class=tdNext>
            <table width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas><a href=?op=annonces&ac=modifier&id_annonce=".$tmp['id']." target=_new>Modifier</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center class=cadreBas><a href='' onClick=\"valid_delete('".$tmp['id']."'); return false;\">Supprimer</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=center><a href='' onClick='changeAff(".$tmp['id']."); return false;' id='changeAff_".$tmp['id']."'>".($tmp['affiche'] == 1 ? 'Mettre hors ligne' : 'Mettre en ligne')."</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align=center class='tdNext gris'>
        <p style=\"color:#444;\">
            &nbsp;".nl2br($tmp['push_res']).'</p>';
        if (is_array($tabHisto[$tmp['id']])) {
            echo '<p style="color:#888; padding-top:5px;">';
            foreach($tabHisto[$tmp['id']] as $histo) {
                echo $histo['type_modif'].' '.HumanDateTime($histo['date']).' par '.$histo['user'];
                if ($histo['new_annonce']) {
                    echo ' [New ID : <a href="index.php?op=annonces&search4='.$histo['new_annonce'].'">'.$histo['new_annonce'].'</a>]';
                }
                echo '<br />';
            }
            echo '</p>';
        }
        echo "
        </td>
        <td align=center>&nbsp;".$tmp['source'];
        if (!empty($tmp['source_ref'])) {
            echo '<br /><a href="redirect.php?site='.$tmp['source_ref'].'" target="_blank">Voir original</a>';
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';
        if (isset($doublon) && !$isDoublon) {
            $query2 = " SELECT a.*, rp.pays0, rp.code_pays
                        FROM annonces a
                        INNER JOIN ref_pays rp ON rp.id = a.pays
                        WHERE a.id_societe = '".$tmp['id_societe']."'
                            AND a.contrat = '".$tmp['id_contrat']."'
                            AND a.domaine = '".$tmp['domaine']."'
                            AND a.id != '".$tmp['id']."'
                            AND ADDDATE(a.date_creation, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) > '".$tmp['date_creation']."'
                            AND a.poste = \"".addslashes($tmp['poste'])."\"
                            AND a.ville = \"".addslashes($tmp['ville'])."\"
                            AND a.societe = \"".addslashes($tmp['societe'])."\"
                            AND (a.id_societe != 1
                                     OR (a.id_societe = 1 AND a.contact_email = \"".$tab_annonce['contact_email']."\"))
                        ORDER BY a.id DESC";
            $tabAnnonces2   = $db->getTab($query2);
            if (count($tabAnnonces2) > 0) {
                $tabId = array();
                foreach($tabAnnonces2 as $annonc) {
                    $tabId[] = $annonc['id'];
                }
                $tmpListAnnonceTab = annoncelist::getHistorique($tabId);
                $tmpTabHisto = createTabHisto($tmpListAnnonceTab);
                $tabHisto += $tmpTabHisto;  //Additionne les 2 tableaux, contrairement à array_merge il garde les clés !!
                affAnnonce($tabAnnonces2, 1);
                foreach($tabAnnonces2 AS $tmpAnn)
                    $tabNoAffAnnonce[]  = $tmpAnn['id'];
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Only this script is slow, all the others on the same server/domain/directory work great.
On an other server, the same script works fine.
The script takes up to 90% of CPU when running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. 
It was the php error handler that was not correctly disabled.

Comment: Did you just completely disable error reporting entirely or reduce what was reported?  I'm running into some weird mmap/munmap while testing php 7 and this is one of the few posts I've seen mentioning similar behavior.

Comment: Hey, any news ? Can you be more specific ? PHP 7.1 here.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013646/php-fpm7-1-mmap-munmap-very-slow-performance