# php-fpm is busywaiting with a loop of mmap calls

Tags: php

I have a PHP script running in browser, it runs for a while then ends up with Service Unavailable

Running top shows a php-fpm process pegging the CPU near 100%, strace shows an infinite loop of:

```
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4549600000
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php-fpm7.1 mmap/munmap (very) slow performance on virtualized systems (hugepage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013646/php-fpm7-1-mmap-munmap-very-slow-performance-on-virtualized-systems-hugepage)

Comment: Nope. Not at all. That's a performance problem with mmap/munmap/madvise. This is an infinite loop with mmap only. Typical Stackoverflow.

Comment: @emptyhua now check my answer. Don't be so hasty on closing questions.

Comment: I did not see the PHP code, so I can only infer from the error message.

Comment: @emptyhua which, again, has _nothing_ to do with that question except for a mmap call. Significant differences include a) lack of other calls b) erroring out instead of being slow. I am trying to educate you here so others will have a better SO experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a userspace infinite recursion and the mmap calls were allocating stack space.